# DateDiff alternative in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to get results if there are records where the date falls between two fields: start and finish.  The linq query I have doesn't seem to return any results:

```
var alerts = from q in db.AlertMsgs 
             where (q.Start >= DateTime.Now
             && q.Finish <= DateTime.Now)
             select q;
```

Any suggestions on why this is?    I've also tried

```
var alerts = from q in AlertMsgs.Where(q => q.Start.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) > 0
&& q.Finish.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 1)
 select q;
```

without any luck either.

Comment: What do you mean `q.start >= now && q.finish <= now`? this means just now, whatever that is both started and finished at right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your conditions backwards.  Try:

```
var alerts = from q in db.AlertMsgs 
             where (q.Start < DateTime.Now && q.Finish > DateTime.Now) 
             select q;
```

Or, using the method syntax (and `<=`/`>=`, in case you want that comparison):

```
var alerts = db.AlertMsgs
               .Where(q => q.Start <= DateTime.Now && q.Finish >= DateTime.Now);
```

This will give you all messages which have already started (`Start < Now`) and have not yet finished (`Finish > Now`).  What you were searching for was messages which haven't started yet (or started *exactly* now), but which have already finished (or finished *exactly now*).  This would only return an item which had the same start and end time, and where both times were exactly `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: I swear I tried those conditions and received ZERO results.  It may have been in Linqpad, which I"m still trying to figure out.